# How to install the proper package to access tool?

Tags: package-management

In the Ubuntu manpage I found the `zlib` utility:

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man3/zlib.3tcl.html

However, it is not clear what `apt-get install` command I need to access this utility. What is the proper method to see what to install?

Comment: That's not a shell command but [a command for TCL](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Tcl_Programming/Introduction)

Answer (score 2):

`zlib` is a library that's used by other packages. In this case, the manpage you link to is provided by [`tcl`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/tcl), which indicates that this is a TCL command, and not a shell command.

`zlib` is installed by default, since it's also used by Ubuntu's and Debian's package management system `dpkg`, and the default GNU zip utility `gzip.`

If you know the package name (in this case `zlib1g`) you can use this command to see which other packages depend on it:

```
apt rdepends zlib1g
```

For this particular package, you'll see a rather long list, since almost any application depending on compression will use `zlib` by default.

Comment: It's used by the infamous `gzip` ... Just a tiny note :-) ... Recursive reverse dependencies can be listed with e.g. `apt-cache rdepends -i --installed --recurse zlib1g` ... Prints all installed packages that have `zlib1g` in their dependency tree be it direct or inherited.